# Resizing with custom PyQt4 QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I have made custom QTableWidget class and put it in the layout, where user is allowed to move from cell to cell by using arrow buttons after editing data in the first cell (instead TABs). There are several hundred rows in the table, but you can see only 15 in one moment. When I edit data in cell and press any arrow button, table should be resized with no horizontal scrolling.
I have written the method to do this and connected `cellChanged(int, int)` signal to it, but it works only for the visible part of the table, but not to all the table.

```
def window_resize(self):
    w = 0
    self.resizeRowsToContents()
    self.resizeColumnsToContents()
    for i in range(self.columnCount()):
        w += self.columnWidth(i)

    self.setFixedSize(w + self.horizontalHeader().height() + 2 * self.autoScrollMargin(), 400)
```